# How can I debug processing of hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files value combined with hsqldb?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hsqldb, spring-test-mvc

In a Java project I'm working on I've got the following setup for our unit tests:

- I'm using Spring Test MVC, `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and `@WebAppConfiguration` to run the unit tests, and I create a `MockMvc` instance using `webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)` to test the application.
- I've got a Hibernate config to set up an in-memory HSQLDB, all tables are created based on the @Entity classes.
- In the Hibernate config, I'm setting the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property to load a file `import.sql` with SQL statements to populate the (in-memory) database.

Now, I've confirmed all these above work:

- Tests can successfully insert/retrieve from the in-memory DB.
- The SQL statements in the `import.sql` are executed, as various tests confirm.

Now the **problem**: Errors occurring with statements I add in `import.sql` don't seem to be reported anywhere, neither is any indication given that an error occurred at all. Instead, subsequent statements are simply not executed. (I've confirmed this through testing.)

Is there any way or place these errors *are* reported that I'm apparently unaware of? Is there an additional Hibernate property for this?

Excerpt from hibernate test config:

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory" name="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class,hbm</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">sa</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password"></prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:myschema</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">configuration/test/import.sql</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor">org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor</prop>
                <!-- when using type="yes_no" for booleans, the line below allow booleans in HQL expressions: -->
                <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get exceptions to log, like @Julien Kroneg suggested.

But I **was** able to put a breakpoint in the catch block of the method `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport#importScript` where `trimmedSql` represents each SQL statement as it's being applied:

```
catch ( Exception e ) {
    if (haltOnError) {
        throw new ImportScriptException( "Error during statement execution (file: '"
                + namedReader.getName() + "'): " + trimmedSql, e );
    }
    exceptions.add(e);
    LOG.unsuccessful(trimmedSql);
    LOG.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

It may be enough, given how init scripts are static and not really business data, once you get them to work, they hopefully *keep working*.

Comment: This was the second best solution that I was using until I implemented the best solution which was eliminating using import scripts altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question, but alternative way to handle test DB population.

There is a XML namespace in Spring called `jdbc` that allows you to prepopulate your database with initial data during Spring context startup. Also it reports errors in your SQLs just fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">

    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="org/mytestproject/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="org/mytestproject/schema-hsqldb.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="org/mytestproject/data-hsqldb.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="${jdbc.validationQuery}"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks for offering this alternative. When I implement it an error occurs regarding the non-existence of a used table. Could it be that this method executes the import.sql prior to Hibernate auto-creating the tables?

Comment: Yes, add depends on hibernate sessionFactory. In my sample Spring creates and drops tables directly in SQL

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with having to use Hibernate's auto-creating here... Thanks anyways though, any further suggestions are welcome!

Comment: have you tried `depends-on='sessionFactory'` in `initialize-database` bean?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your comment! I'm being told (by my IDE and when I run it) that that's not a valid attribute for the `initialize-database` tag. Did I add it in the wrong spot?

Comment: Oh you are right, I thought it should be there. Disregard my last comment

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the logging on class `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport` with level TRACE.

Some errors are logged at DEBUG level (e.g. file not found):

```
10:29:21,039 DEBUG SchemaExport:353 - Import file not found: ../myFile.sql
```